# Two simple updates is deadlocking

Tags: sql-server

```
Update tbl1 set col1 = 1 where id = 1
```

The same update ran a few miliseconds apart. It causes deadlock. Id is primary clustered key.

I read about lock partition. is there any other way to resolve this kind of deadlock?

Please see below Deadlock graph. Thanks.

unknown    
unknown    
(@P0 int,@P1 int)UPDATE Tbl1 SET Col1=@P0 WHERE  Col2 =@P1                   
unknown    
unknown    
(@P0 int,@P1 int)UPDATE Tbl1 SET Col1=@P0 WHERE  Col2 =@P1

Comment: What have you tried up to this point? How much data is in the table? What else is happening while this update runs? Is there an explicit transaction involved? How long does it run for?

Comment: We'll need more info for the question to be answered. Please provide the `CREATE TABLE` statement with all the indexes and the complete deadlock graph. Also confirm whether the transactions involved are composed from a single (UPDATE) statement each or more that you omitted, and that the statements are exactly these you show (and no hints omitted, etc). What is the isolation level used?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you running the same update?

Try as this will not take a lock if col1 = 1

```
Update tbl1 
set col1 = 1 
where id = 1
  and col1 <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to me that SQL Server would try to escalate to a shared table-level lock for a trivial update via the primary key. Check the execution plan to ensure the primary key index is being used as expected.

It seems you may have a data type mismatch for the `id` column value or parameter, resulting in a scan instead of clustered index seek.

Comment: In execution plan, it is clustered index update. ID is a clustered primary key.

Comment: @AMMH, although this question is closed, upload the plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and share the link here. I think there is a missing detail.